# unaligned data frame when writing a tsv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a large dataframe that pretty much looks like this

```
    gene1   gene2   gene3
cell1   0   1   2
cell2   1   1   0
cell3   0   0   1
```

I transposed it `countst=as.data.frame(t(counts))`
, and it seemed to work fine

```
    cell1   cell2   cell3   
gene1   0   1   0
gene2   1   1   0
gene3   2   0   1
```

but when I try to write the file with

```
write.table(countst, file='counts.tsv')
```

I get a tsv that looks like this

```
cell1   cell2   cell3   
gene1   0   1   0
gene2   1   1   0
gene3   2   0   1
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Tab-delimited does not mean all columns will line up, it's just a mechanism to facilitate differentiating fields on a row. If you want a properly-rendered table that is column-aligned, you need fixed-width output, which is really a rendering, not a storage method.

If you want it to look good in the file (and are not concerned about reading it back in later), then you can use something like:

```r
writeLines(capture.output(print(t(dat))), "cells.tab")
```

which produces a file that looks like:

```
      cell1 cell2 cell3
gene1     0     1     0
gene2     1     1     0
gene3     2     0     1
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(gene1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), gene2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L), gene3 = c(2L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("cell1", "cell2", "cell3"))
```

Comment: Hello revans, thank you for the feedback. What I mean is not exactly how the file looks, is that this changes the data structure, as the first row ends up with with less columns than the rest of the data, which turns into a problem when I try to read it using other packages!

Comment: Is your problem, then, that the default for `row.names=` is true? Row names in a CSV/TSV will always create a pseudo-column. If that's the case, I suggest you convert them to an explicit column instead.